# Problem with WCF service and Windows Mobile

Tags: wcf, windows-mobile, compact-framework, window, dmz

I have a very simple wcf service. And a simple windows mobile client.

I have two Windows 2008 servers. One is my development pc. The other is placed in our dmz.

If I deploy my application to my development pcs, IIS, and open a port all the way in(Just for test). It works.

But if I copy the service on to the dmz server, it doesn't.

I have setup both machines myself, and I can reach the service from internet explore on the mobile device.

I've also created a std. winforms test client, and the service works on the dmz, just not from the mobile device...

Any idears what to do?

/adelo

Comment: can you show us some config? What does your server's config look like? What bindings are you using? Where are you hosting your service - in IIS, or are your self-hosting?

Comment: Hosting in IIS.. Problem seems to have solved it self. 

I choose to forget about it for at couple of days, and then try from the beginning with netcfsvcutil and then it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure option "World Wide Web-services (HTTP)" in Windows Firewall exceptions is checked/enabled.

I ran into this same problem just today.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to security.

Is the difference between the winforms test client and the mobile, that when you are running the winforms app, you are logged in to the domain?

Comment: The service and the winform application is not in the same domain.

I choose to forget about it for at couple of days, and then try from the beginning with netcfsvcutil and then it worked!